# HTML css - width of element than 100% width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to append a tooltip to a list/div block of elements - but these elements are set at 100% width. I'd like to have it so the tool tip is only appearing a few px away from the last word in the list/sentence.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code to start off with?

Comment: Can you add your code snippet here?

Comment: if I set the elements to display:inline-block - it will cause the tool tip to rest along side - but then break the structure - they will all nest together

Comment: I'm guessing you need something like this example: https://codepen.io/rjanjic/pen/yRKjjv

Comment: yeah its ok - I added a wrapper - and its working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it html + css only, you need to wrap each line in a div, like

```css
.gray-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray-container">
  <div class="line"><input type="radio">None<div class="tooltip"></div></div>
  <div class="line"><input type="radio">Two</div>
  <div class="line"><input type="radio">Three</div>
  <div class="line"><input type="radio">Four</div>
</div>
```

Now for demo purposes and because i don't have any idea of the methods you're using to create the tooltips since you didn't post your code i'm using a div with `class="tooltip"`, but this solves your question of the div being 100%.

Comment: I added a wrapper - like the gray container - but a display block -- and those line divs are more like display- inline-blocks

Comment: Exactly, you beat me by 10 secs, i was testing it on codepen :), updated with the working snippet, i also set the tooltip to absolute so it won't change the .line height when it appears